# removeRow() doesn't work for multiple rows in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm attempting to delete multiple row from a [Kendo UI Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid). I first tried configuring the grid to allow multiple rows to be selected, and then calling [`Grid.removeRow()`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-removeRow) on each selected row, but somehow this prevented any editor template selects from displaying.

The configuration:

```
// ...
.Selectable(selectable =>
  {
      selectable.Enabled(true);
      selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple);
  })
// ...
```

The remove button logic:

```
// ...
var grid = $("#TimesheetGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.select().each(function (index, item)
{
    grid.removeRow(item);
});
// ...
```

Since select elements weren't working in my editor templates, I removed the config line to enable multiple row selection and added a checkbox column instead.

```
// ...
.Selectable(selectable =>
  {
      selectable.Enabled(true);
  })
// ...

// ...
$("#MyGrid tbody tr td.select input[type=checkbox]").each(function (index, item)
{
    if ($(item).is(":checked"))
    {
        var $row = $(item).parents("tr");
        grid.removeRow($row);
    }
});
// ...
```

This also didn't work. In IE, it deletes the first selected row, and then ignores the rest. What am I missing? I'm using Kenudo UI version 2013.2.716.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that calling `removeRow()` in IE breaks something related to traversing the remaining checked rows. I was able to solve this by populating an array of rows to delete, then deleting each item.

```
var deleting = new Array();

$("#MyGrid tbody tr td.select input[type=checkbox]").each(function (index, item)
{
    if ($(item).is(":checked"))
    {
        var $row = $(item).parents("tr");
        deleting.push($row);
    }
});

$.each(deleting, function(index, item)
{
    grid.removeRow(item);
});
```